# GXT(EXT-GWT) Cannot commit changes to EditorGrid store

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I have an EditorGrid. When i edit the grid i use `grid.getStore().commitChanges()`, in order to save all the changes to the grid's store.

Then i print out each row of the grid's store. It return's the previous values and not the updated ones.

I searched sensha ext-gwt forum, but couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can have updated done on your *Store*  by adding a *StoreListener*  to the store of your Grid 
see the javadoc [here](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/gxtdocs/com/extjs/gxt/ui/client/store/StoreListener.html)

```
   grid.getStore().addStoreListener(new StoreListener<BeanModel>(){

        @Override
        public void storeAdd(StoreEvent<BeanModel> se) {

        }

        @Override
        public void storeRemove(StoreEvent<BeanModel> se) {


        }

        @Override
        public void storeUpdate(StoreEvent<BeanModel> se) {

        }

    });
```